# Open and read the text of the email (from Gmail) with a specific title with Selenium/Katalon (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, email, gmail, katalon-studio

I would like to:

- open Gmail

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox");
```

- research a title

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']")).sendKeys("Title");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.gb_2e.gb_df > svg")).click();
```

- open and store the text of all the emails with that title (maybe located in different pages)

How can I do it?

Comment: You already done it? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Yes I tried to implement it, but I have a problem with the condition inside the while loop because it can't find the button to change page. I tried the cssSelector suggested by C. Peck but i have this error: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable". How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after you have searched for your text I guess the next thing would be to figure out how to click each element on the current page, then handle pagination.

For me, the following CSS selector finds all the email elements on the page:

```
WebElement[] listOfEmailElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('tbody > tr.zA'));
```

If, for example you have 50 results on that page it will return an array containing those 50 webElements.

Now, we have to loop through the emails, clicking on each one, then click on the ... icon and download the email, and return to the main page all inside the for loop.

```
for (WebElement element: listOfEmailElements) {
    element[i].click();

    //The following is the only way I could find to uniquely identify the '...' icon

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('div.T-I.J-J5-Ji.T-I-Js-Gs.aap.T-I-awG.T-I-ax7.L3').click();


    //Couldn't find a way to uniquely identify the "Download" button but the following selector gets
    //an array of options from the list you just opened above and download is at an index of 16

    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('div.cj'))[16].click();

    //simply use the browser's back button to navigate back to the main list

    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

OK, now we just have to handle pagination.

It looks to me like the caret icon that goes to the next page, when enabled, is uniquely identified by

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('div.T-I.J-J5-Ji.amD.T-I-awG.T-I-ax7.T-I-Js-Gs.L3'))
```

However, when the button is disabled, that selector finds two elements.  I think this makes it so that the following code will do what you want:

```
while (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('div.T-I.J-J5-Ji.amD.T-I-awG.T-I-ax7.T-I-Js-Gs.L3')).size() == 1) {
        for (WebElement element: listOfEmailElements) {
            element[i].click();

            //The following is the only way I could find to uniquely identify the '...' icon

           driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('div.T-I.J-J5-Ji.T-I-Js-Gs.aap.T-I-awG.T-I-ax7.L3').click();


           //Couldn't find a way to uniquely identify the "Download" button but the following selector gets
           //an array of options from the list you just opened above and download is at an index of 16

           driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('div.cj'))[16].click();

           //simply use the browser's back button to navigate back to the main list

           driver.navigate().back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I used a similar solution but I have a problem with the condition inside the while loop because it can't find the button to change page specified by that cssSelector. It returns this error: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable". How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you upload a the full error text so I can tell which attempt to find an element is causing the error?  The I would add a wait for the element to be visible before attempting to click it.

Comment: Using this test code: 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.T-I.J-J5-Ji.amD.T-I-awG.T-I-ax7.T-I-Js-Gs.L3"))); 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.T-I.J-J5-Ji.amD.T-I-awG.T-I-ax7.T-I-Js-Gs.L3")).click(); 
I have: imgur.com/a/O20rsJI
while, without the wait: imgur.com/bYgzGTg